# How to aggregate column based multiple conditions for better performance?

Tags: sql, hive

I have a billion row table with data in format like -

```
id  col1 col2
1   100  21
1   110  22
1   120  21
1   20   35
2   230  22
2   2    22
3   456  31
3   30   21
3   2    31
4   200  33
5   45   34
```

I need to find min and max of col1 based on various conditions on col2 and get resultant table. Currently I am doing using left joining table with itself but this is not efficient and its taking over 70 minutes .

Sample query I am running now looks like this -

```
select distinct t.id, t1.m1 colA,t2.m2 colB,t3.m3 colC
from table1 t
left join (select id,min(col1) over (partition by id) m1  from table1 where col2=21) t1 on (t.id=t1.id)  
left join (select id,min(col1) over (partition by id) m2 from table1 where col2 in (22,23,34) ) t2 on (t.id=t2.id) 
left join (select id,max(col1) over (partition by id) m3 from table1 id where col2 in (21,33,22,35) )t3 on (t.id=t3.id)
```

Is there any better way to achieve same result in more efficient way in **hive 1.2** ?

result of above query is  :

```
id  colA    colB   colC 
1   100     110    120
2   NULL    2      230
3   30      NULL   30
4   NULL    NULL   200
5   NULL    45     NULL
```

PS : Col1 is actually a timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using "conditional aggregates", which basically means placing a case expression inside an aggregate function:

```
select
      t.id
    , max(case when col2=21 then t.col1 end)              colA
    , min(case when col2 in (22,23,34) then t.col1 end)   colB
    , max(case when col2 in (21,33,22,35 then t.col1 end) colC
from table1 t
group by t.id
```

This should provide fewer passes through the source table that multiple left joins.

Also note that whilst "select distinct" may have produced the wanted outcome, it is an "expensive" option. `GROUP BY` also produces unique rows but also provides the ability to aggregate at the same time.

Comment: Great! This is brilliantly simple solution. For the table above it brought down performance from 120 sec to just 20 secs.